# No animation in Curves on using Bake sound to fcurves

Tags: drivers, audio, fcurves

In Blender 2.9, on adding location drivers to the origin of a Curve, `there is no animation even though the location values are generated by baking sound to fcurves`.

Also using a Hook driver to drive the curves creates no animation. Even trying with a Cube, gives no result.

Also, there is an  Error - "Invalid python expression". Since the location values are derived from sound, there is no option to link the driver "var" to this value. I tried using "self", but no result.

How to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Original audio fcurves were created in the `Driver` tab (after adding driver to the object property and baking sound).
Eventhough this creates fcurves in the driver tab, the animation just doesn't play.

Solved the issue by baking audio fcurves from the `GraphEditor` instead(after setting keyframes for the object property).

Answer (score 0):

In the 3D window go to the menu Object - Animation - Bake action, so to bake the sound created animation into an editable curve.

Comment: On baking audio fcurve to action , only 2 keyframes get created (first and last) .The inbetween keyframes are missing.

Comment: Could you upload your file?